# Modifying parts of the integer-like string

Tags: python

For any k-digit integer i, the goal is to produce an m-digit string where the first n digits, where n=m-k are zeros, say. Using python would be helpful.

For example, given m=5 and i=324, how to produce "00324"?

EDIT:
The `zfill` function pads the integer with zeros. Is there any more general function that pads the integer with an arbitrary integer/character?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zfill`

```
i = 324
m = 5
s = str(i).zfill(m)
# '00324'
```